# I am looking at way to create an accessibility label for a simple text box in Xamarin.Form using Visual Studio on MAC

Tags: xamarin.forms, accessibility

I have tried using instructions from various forums but can't get it working. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Here is the sample code I am working on:                   "

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility label will be available from the box in future XF release.
currently you can add this feature only by manual for your app:

see link - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/accessibility/